# move an element that match html to the match element

Tags: jquery

```
<div class="Label" id="Label1">
<h2>Menu</h2>
<ul>
<li>
<a dir="ltr" href="#">Sub</a>
</li>
<li>
<a dir="ltr" href="#">Sub2</a>
</li>
<li>
<a dir="ltr" href="#">Sub3</a>
</li>
</ul>
<div>
...
```

and the sub menu:

```
<div class="Label" id="Label2">
<h2>Sub</h2>
<ul>
<li>
<a dir="ltr" href="#">Sub-child-1</a>
</li>
<li>
<a dir="ltr" href="#">Sub-child-2</a>
</li>
</ul>
<div>

<div class="Label" id="Label3">
<h2>Sub2</h2>
<ul>
<li>
<a dir="ltr" href="#">Sub2-child-1</a>
</li>
<li>
<a dir="ltr" href="#">Sub2-child-2</a>
</li>
</ul>
<div>

....
```

I want a code that compare the $('.Label h2').html() match to the $('.Label a').html() and then move "the 'div' that contain the match" to after "the 'a' match with.

```
$('.Label a').each(function(){
  if( $(this).html() == $('.Label h2').html() ){ 
      $(this).parent('li').append('$('.Label h2').parent('div')')
  };
});
```

notwork @@ please help me!

Comment: Check out the syntax highlighting that you see on here, this should give you a clue to your first problem.

Comment: like http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/kSvCR/1/

Answer (score 0):

This code will do the job for you. but because of the css of your page it will look like a mess one. you should modify your css. I has added SubLabel class to the moved one (submenu).

```
$('.Label a').each(function(){
  var that = this;
  $('.Label h2').each(function(){
      if($(that).html() === $(this).html()){
         $(that).append($(this).parent().addClass('SubLabel'));
      }
  });
});
```

Comment: sorry for my mistake here .append('$('.Label h2').parent('div').

Comment: Simple. I mean move all Sub menu into the menu by using match html() betwen "H2" and "a" tag

Comment: http://trinhkienco.blogspot.com/ here is my blog. I want to move "Phần mềm" to Tổng Hợp" (contain:ASCII,..., Phần mềm, ...). And any other that the name (H2) match will be move and move and move ...automatic. sorry for bad english.

Comment: $('.Label a').each(function(){
      var subhold = this;
      $('.Label h2').each(function(){
          if($(subhold).html() === $(this).html()){
             $(subhold).parent('li').append($(this).parent('div'));
          }
      });
    });

help me plz! I think this code is the good way. but the var (subhold) in the second function is not hightlight. so i think the var is not work :( something's wrong

Comment: I has updated the script to solve your problem. but another is occur. now, submenu is move like you want but you have to fix their css. please look on updated answer :)

Comment: Sorry! the code that i post at above comment is work perfect for this case. I do, do, do and forget this $(document).ready(function () {. I'm a stupid guy! @@

Comment: I think you should edit the code in answer to (clear the ":first" and "gt(0)") because it's just do for first only. Thank you very much  Chokchai!